# How to give the static value to HashMap?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-emulator, android-widget

I have HashMap like:

```
static HashMap<String,ArrayList<Media>> mediaListWithCategory=new HashMap<String,ArrayList<Media>>();
```

I have value like:

```
January:
   -Sunday
   -Monday
Februsry:
   -Saturday
   -Sunday
   -Thursday
March:
   -Monday
   -Tuesday
   -Wednesday
```

How can I statically assign these values when defining the hash map?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can populate it in a static block:

```
static {
   map.put("January", Arrays.asList(new Media("Sunday"), new Media("Monday")));
}
```

(You should prefer interface to concrete classes. define your type as `Map<String, List<Media>>`)

Comment: If it is String instead of the Media then should i have to define "new" keyword for the new string object ?

Comment: ok. I have solve it by this one:    mediaListWithCategory.put("January",(ArrayList<String>) Arrays.asList("sunday","gdahdga") );

Answer (score 4):

Use a static block:

```
static {
  mediaListWithCategory.put(youKey, yourValue);
}
```

Comment: If there ia multiple value in to yourValue then ?

Comment: You can write whatever code is appropriate in the static block. I thought your question was about static initialization. Do you need help in constructing your map structure?

Answer (score 1):

A variant of this may be more succinct:

```
static HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>() {{
    put("January", new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Sunday");
        add("Monday");
      }});
    put("Februsry" /* sic. */, new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Saturday");
        add("Sunday");
        add("Thursday");
      }});
    put("March", new ArrayList<String>() {{
        add("Monday");
        add("Tuesday");
        add("Wednesday");
      }});
}};
```

See [Double Brace Initialisation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1958636/what-is-double-brace-initialization-in-java) for discussion.