# Java statically defined dictionary / HashMap

Tags: java, dictionary, hashmap

I have a block of static data that I need to organize into an array containing hash maps. Specifically, I want to have a static object in my app that contains the time zone information like this: https://gist.github.com/pamelafox/986163

Seeing how clean the definition looks like in Python, and knowing how a similarly clean definition can be created with some of the other languages I know, I was hoping there is a cleaner approach to it in Java then just running `map.put(...)` repeatedly. I have seen this question: [How to give the static value to HashMap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8211784/how-to-give-the-static-value-to-hashmap) but what wondering if there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to store the data as a normal string in whatever format you can think of and then convert the string representation into the map (static, non-static or as a one-time initialized instance).

An improvement of this method would be to store the data in a file and load it (can be included in .jar package, when you use jar). This solution would have the advantage that data can be easily updated.